# How to keep what is drawn on panel and save to bitmap when the "CLEAR" button is pressed?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I want to finish my paint program for my Daughter and am having issues with the panel keeping drawings rendered on the panel when the application is minimized. I would also like for the program to automatically save to a file what she drew on the panel when she clicks on the "CLEAR" and/or "CLOSE" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your drawings you could instead of drawing in the graphics of the panel draw inside a Image of that panel nonetheless you can use Panel.DrawToImage() it should be like this

```
Panel.DrawToBitmap(Bitmap, Panel.ClientRectangle);
Bitmap bmp; //this will be the image where you would draw to
Graphics g; // the graphics
public ALANA_PAINT()
{
    //do your stuff
    bmp = new Bitmap(Width,Height)// Initialize the bitmap
    Panel.BackgroundImage = bmp;
    g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
}

//your normal drawing methods

public void Save()
{
   bmp.Save(path,imageFormat);
}
```

For the close function the forms have a FormsClosing event that you could call you save from there

Comment: I am really a noob sorry... Looking at your answer and trying to figure out how to implement your answer. Would I use it in place of the "g = pnl1.CreateGraphics();"?

Comment: Thank you for showing me where to edit and make corrections! I really appreciate all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

you are going to need a method like this one for the 2nd part of your question :

```
public void SaveBitmap(string location)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)myPanel.Width, (int)myPanel.Height);
    DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, myPanel.Width, myPanel.Height));

    using (FileStream saveStream = new FileStream(location + ".bmp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
    {
        bmp.Save(saveStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
    }                       
}
```

If you want to handle it when she closes the window, use the `Closing` event in the Window.

Comment: Thank you for the method. I will see how I can implement it towards to bottom of the code. Thank you all for replying! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You need to not put the drawing code in `pnl1_MouseMove` against a new `Graphics` you get from `pnl1.CreateGraphics();`. You need to do one of two things.

1) Keep a list of all the "shapes" that need to be drawn and redraw, then subscribe to the event `pn1.Paint += pn1_Paint` and have that paint method go through the list of all the shapes you have recorded and re draw them

or

2) Don't paint to the Graphics object for the panel, call `CreateGraphics` on a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you have in the class then have that bitmap drawn as the background of `pn1`.

The benefit of method 2 is it will allow most of your code to be the same, you are now just drawing against a bitmap instead of directly against the panel.

Comment: Would this be like declaring a variable like "Bitmap bmp1;" then changing the "g = pnl1.CreateGraphics();" to be more like "g = pnl1.CreateGraphics(Bitmap bmp1,);" Sorry.. I am a noob programmer and am asking a lot of questions. Thank you all for replying!